# Pronunciation of luxury

Tags: pronunciation

Is there a reason that Americans now pronounce luxury "lugsury" instead of "lucshury" while still pronouncing "extract" and "extra" with the more common "x" sound?

Comment: I am American, and I don't do that.  Perhaps they forgot to send me the memo.

Comment: Dammit, I knew I had one other thing in my inbox that day. Sorry phoog!

Comment: I would say that my pronunciation varies between the two, with the latter being more likely.  Depends in part on how luxurious I'm feeling, I suppose.

Comment: The x in 'luxury' is in a different phonetic environment from the x in 'extra', which is immediately followed by voiceless plosive, so more likely to be pronounced /ks/.  BTW, in British English, we usually pronounce the 'x' as /ks/ in 'luxury', but as /gzh/ in 'luxurious', so how the word is stressed comes into it as well.  [Excuse the 'zh' - can't get at IPA symbols right now.]

Comment: I've always heard it as a hard "K" followed by "shh" sound, so my preference is: Luck'-shur-ree.

Comment: "Phonetic environment' says it all. In a really unusual environment some native English speakers are completely thrown by x. Witness the incognoscenti trying to read aloud 'Xavier'.

Comment: @PhilipWood I’m not sure the cognoscenti are much better there – I’d say [z] and [ɪgz] are about equally common whether you’re cognoscent or not. Etymologically, of course, it ought to be [tʃ], but not even the cognoscentest of the cognoscenti would dream of pronouncing it like that.

Comment: And there's Ekzavier.

Answer (score 2):

As David Garner mentioned in a comment, "extract" and extra" wouldn't be pronounced with a /g/ sound because the x is before /t/ in these words.

The letter "x" is sometimes pronounced with /g/ + a voiced fricative sound when it comes before a vowel; mainly when the following vowel is stressed (as in *exact*). In *luxury,* the following vowel is not stressed, but in the related word *luxurious,* it is. So it seems likely that the pronunciation of *luxury* with /g/ is derived from the pronunciation of *luxurious* with /g/. I don't know why there would be a difference between British and American speakers. As was mentioned in the comments, not all American English speakers use /g/ in *luxury*: some use /k/.

Comment: An analogous difference is /'Ek sIt/ vs. /'Eg zIt/ for _exit._